# Swift 5 Datetime Conversion triple timezone cast (???)

Tags: date, swiftui, uikit, swift5

I have a DateTime that I'm reading from an API that is in GMT.

I want to force cast it to an EST date object.

The original object is a string that I then cast to a Date to do some time comparison. Unfortunately, I don't think I did this right which made me do this unholy abomination:

```
    extension String {
    
    //this force casts from our original data being in GMT to EST
    func getDateTimeTZ() -> Date{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
            let localTime = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
            return dateFormatter.date(from: localTime)!
        }
        
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)!
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, I seem to have to flip the dateformatter 3 times to get the correct EST string output. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` is not associated with a time zone. From [the `Date` reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date#):

> A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone.
>
> ...
>
> A `Date` value encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. `Date` values represent a time interval relative to an absolute reference date.

So there is no such thing as “an EST date object” in the iOS SDK.

Time zones are relevant when converting to or from strings and when manipulating the calendrical components (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, etc.) of a `Date`.

The code you posted computes a new `Date` that is offset from the original date by the time offset between GMT and EST, but the new `Date` is not “an EST date object”.

(Incidentally, `"EST"` means Eastern Standard Time, and will not switch to daylight saving time during the appropriate part of the year. Use `"US/Eastern"` to get the appropriate time conversion depending on the day of year.)

You say you're doing this adjustment “to do some time comparison”, but you don't say what you're comparing to. It would help for you to describe what comparison you're performing.

For example, let's you want to check whether the `Date` is in the range 8:30 AM to 3:00 PM in the US/Eastern time zone, regardless of the day. If the input string is GMT, then you should parse it that way, as you do in your code:

```
let parser = DateFormatter()
parser.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "GMT")
parser.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
let date = parser.date(from: "2021-03-26 19:55")!
```

Then, use a `Calendar` set to the `"US/Eastern"` `TimeZone` to compute the hour and minute components of the `Date`:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "US/Eastern")!
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
let hhmm = components.hour! * 100 + components.minute!
if (08_30 ..< 15_00).contains(hhmm) {
    print("school time")
} else {
    print("play time")
}
```

Comment: Oh that's really interesting. I was doing a comparison to another date object that I'd coded to be the same day but at a specific hour and minute. 

I'll try this thanks!